# In a WPF Grid, how can I find the Row & Column at the mouse location?

Tags: wpf, grid, mouseevent

I have a WPF `Grid` with some rows and columns, e.g.

```
<Grid Name="myGrid" MouseMove="OnMouseMove">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

With a handler for `MouseMove` in the .cs file, e.g.

```
private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.GetPosition(myGrid);

    // What row & col is the mouse over?
}
```

I want to be able to find which row and column in the grid the mouse is over, is this possible?

[Note: this is a simplified version of the problem, so it looks a little odd to present it in this way - it's part of some drag & drop between grids functionality]

Comment: Look into the drag/drop functionality in FluidKit.  You won't have to worry about hacky shnit like this.

Comment: I'm already using FluidKit, that 'MouseMove' is really 'OnDropCompleted' and the mouse position is really 'dropPoint' - I want to be able to drop into specific cells on the table, which I haven't been able to get working yet.

Answer (score 19):

I hope you have already find a solution. I faced to the same problem and I found this unanswered post. So I think the next one will be happy to find this solution :

```
private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (UIElement)e.Source;

    int c = Grid.GetColumn(element);
    int r = Grid.GetRow(element);
}
```

Comment: This only works, if you have UIElements in each cell. So it is no answer to the asked question.

Comment: @GreenEyedAndy To solve this, you could just add a transparent border to each row, with a column span that matches the total columns in that row. Hit testing will get that border, and it will work on all cells regardless if they're filled or not. This would also facilitate a highlight feature of the rows by changing the background of said row's transparent border to a color, if desired.

Answer (score 6):

This the following can be done (but shouldn't be used on larger Grids). It is only for Rows, but a second loop can be applied to the columns...

The answer of Nicolas only works if the grid contains some UIElements (whose position in the grid are determined - I guess that would also cause trouble if an element spans several rows/columns).

```
    private void ItemsGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        double y = e.GetPosition(ItemsGrid).Y;
        double start = 0.0;
        int row = 0;
        foreach(RowDefinition rd in ItemsGrid.RowDefinitions)
        {
            start += rd.ActualHeight;
            if (y < start)
            {
                break;
            }
            row++;
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Row : " + row);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class GridExtentions
{
    public static T Parent<T>(this DependencyObject root) where T : class
    {
        if (root is T) { return root as T; }

        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(root);
        return parent != null ? parent.Parent<T>() : null;
    }

    public static Point GetColumnRow(this Grid obj, Point relativePoint) { return new Point(GetColumn(obj, relativePoint.X), GetRow(obj, relativePoint.Y)); }
    private static int GetRow(Grid obj, double relativeY) { return GetData(obj.RowDefinitions, relativeY); }
    private static int GetColumn(Grid obj, double relativeX) { return GetData(obj.ColumnDefinitions, relativeX); }

    private static int GetData<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, double value) where T : DefinitionBase
    {
        var start = 0.0;
        var result = 0;

        var property = typeof(T).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Actual"));
        if (property == null) { return result; }

        foreach (var definition in list)
        {
            start += (double)property.GetValue(definition);
            if (value < start) { break; }

            result++;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
    var hit = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, e.GetPosition(this));
    if (hit == null) { return; }

    var grid = hit.VisualHit.Parent<Grid>();
    if (grid == null) { return; }

    var gridPosition = grid.GetColumnRow(e.GetPosition(grid));
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Grid location Row: {1} Column: {0}", gridPosition.X, gridPosition.Y));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope can help. it's working well for my app

```
        public class GridCell
        {
            public int GridRow { get; set; }
            public int GridCol { get; set; }
        }

        private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point point = e.GetPosition(this.myGrid);

            Grid gridTarget = GetLastedGridContainPoint(point, this.myGrid);

            Point pointTarget = this.myGrid.TranslatePoint(point, gridTarget);

            GridCell cell = GetGridCellContainPoint(pointTarget, gridTarget);
        }

        private bool IsPointInGrid(Point relativePoint, Grid grid)
        {
            if (relativePoint.X < 0 || relativePoint.X > grid.ActualWidth ||
                relativePoint.Y < 0 || relativePoint.Y > grid.ActualHeight)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private Grid GetLastedGridContainPoint(Point relativePoint, Grid gridParent)
        {
            Grid gridReturn = null;

            if (gridParent.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                Point relativeChildPoint;
                foreach (UIElement e in gridParent.Children)
                {
                    if (e is Grid)
                    {
                        relativeChildPoint = gridParent.TranslatePoint(relativePoint, (e as Grid));
                        gridReturn = GetLastedGridContainPoint(relativeChildPoint, (e as Grid));

                        if (gridReturn != null)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (gridReturn == null)
            {
                if (IsPointInGrid(relativePoint, gridParent))
                {
                    gridReturn = gridParent;
                }
            }

            return gridReturn;
        }

        private GridCell GetGridCellContainPoint(Point relativePoint, Grid gridTarget)
        {
            if (!IsPointInGrid(relativePoint, gridTarget))
            {
                return null;
            }

            GridCell cell = new GridCell();
            double dbStart = 0;
            double dbEnd = 0;

            if (gridTarget.ColumnDefinitions.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gridTarget.ColumnDefinitions.Count; i++)
                {
                    dbStart = dbEnd;
                    dbEnd += gridTarget.ColumnDefinitions[i].ActualWidth;

                    if (relativePoint.X >= dbStart && relativePoint.X < dbEnd)
                    {
                        cell.GridCol = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            dbStart = 0;
            dbEnd = 0;

            if (gridTarget.RowDefinitions.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gridTarget.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
                {
                    dbStart = dbEnd;
                    dbEnd += gridTarget.RowDefinitions[i].ActualHeight;

                    if (relativePoint.Y >= dbStart && relativePoint.Y < dbEnd)
                    {
                        cell.GridRow = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return cell;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

replace Grid.ColumnDefinitions with reference to Grid component

```
int GetColumn(double point)
{
   int index = 0;
   foreach(var column in Grid.ColumnDefinitions)
   {
      if(point > column.Offset && point < (column.Offset + column.ActualWidth))
          return index;
      index++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly your same problem and I am also using FluidKit. I'm trying to build a form designer where you could drag a control from a Toolbox and drop it into a Grid cell. Here is how I solved it:

I created a grid with two dummy Rectangles in the first row:

```
        <Grid Name="myCanvas" ShowGridLines="True" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle DragDrop:DragDropManager.DropTargetAdvisor="{StaticResource targetAdvisor1}" 
                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" />
            <Rectangle DragDrop:DragDropManager.DropTargetAdvisor="{StaticResource targetAdvisor2}"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" />
        </Grid>
```

It looks as follows:

[image: Grid]

Notice that I defined a DropTargetAdvisor for each of my rectangles, now the logic is as follows:

- You drag/drop a Control from the Toolbox into a Cell
- The `OnDropCompleted` method in the `DropTargetAdvisor` will then remove the rectangle where you're dropping the control and will get its coordinates from the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` Attached properties.
- Once you have the coordinates you can set those Attached properties to your dragged control and add it to your grid.

Here is my `DefaultDropTargetAdvisor.OnDropCompleted` method:

```
public void OnDropCompleted(IDataObject obj, Point dropPoint)
    {
        UIElement dragged_control = ExtractElement(obj);
        //Get the current Rectangle
        FrameworkElement fe = TargetUI as FrameworkElement;
        //Get parent Grid from this Rectangle
        Grid g = fe.Parent as Grid;
        //Get row and columns of this Rectangle
        int row = Grid.GetRow(TargetUI);
        int col = Grid.GetColumn(TargetUI);
        //Remove Rectangle
        g.Children.Remove(TargetUI);
        //Set row and column for the dragged control
        Grid.SetRow(dragged_control, row);
        Grid.SetColumn(dragged_control, col);
        //Add dragged control to Grid in that row/col
        g.Children.Add(dragged_control);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Telerik RadGridView, the best approach if the grid doesn't contain UI elements is to use ChildrenOfType<> in a Linq expression with IsMouseOver.

```
 private void myGridView_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                MyCustomClass myClass = null;

                var rows = this.myGridView.ChildrenOfType<GridViewRow>().Where(r => r.IsMouseOver == true);
                foreach (var row in rows)
                {
                    if (row is GridViewNewRow) break;
                    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)row;
                    myClass = (MyCustomClass)gvr.Item;
                } 
// do something with myClass here if we have found a row under mouse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Andre's answer has a minor mistake, as the coordinates obtained do not account for the row and column headers in the DataGrid. At least this was the case when I implemented the solution in Visual Basic.

You can also modify the examples shown to account for a large DataGrid. It seems to me that the limitation there is based on the scrolled view, so I show two implementations of this correction:

```
Private Sub myGrid_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles myGrid.MouseMove
    Dim total As Double
    Dim myScrollViewer As ScrollViewer = FindVisualChild(Of ScrollViewer)(myGrid)

    Dim cursorPositionX = e.GetPosition(myGrid).X 
    Dim columnIndex As Integer = -1
    total = 0

    'Horizontal offset'        
    Dim rowHeaders As DataGridRowHeader = FindVisualChild(Of DataGridRowHeader)(myGrid)
    cursorPositionX -= (rowHeaders.ActualWidth - myScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset)

    For Each column As DataGridColumn In myGrid.Columns
        If cursorPositionX < total Then Exit For

        columnIndex += 1
        total += column.Width.DisplayValue
    Next

    Dim cursorPositionY = e.GetPosition(myGrid).Y  
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = -1
    total = 0

    'Vertical offset'
    Dim originalOffset As Double = myScrollViewer.VerticalOffset
    Dim colHeadersPresenter As DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter = FindVisualChild(Of DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter)(myGrid)
    cursorPositionY -= colHeadersPresenter.ActualHeight

    For Each row As System.Data.DataRowView In myGrid.Items
        If cursorPositionY < total Then Exit For

        rowIndex += 1
        Dim dgRow As DataGridRow = GetRowByIndex(myGrid, rowIndex)
        total += dgRow.ActualHeight

        'GetRowByIndex will scroll the view to bring the DataGridRow of interest into view, which throws off the counter. This adjusts for that'
        myGrid.UpdateLayout()
        If Not myScrollViewer.VerticalOffset = originalOffset Then myGrid.ScrollIntoView(myGrid.Items(CInt(myScrollViewer.ViewportHeight + originalOffset - 1)))
        myGrid.UpdateLayout()

        If myScrollViewer.VerticalOffset > rowIndex Then cursorPositionY += dgRow.ActualHeight
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that the [ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontaloffset(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a value in Device Independent Pixels, so I merely offset my location once before looping through the columns.

Note that the [ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the number of items if CanContentScroll = True. So in my example, on each loop I offset the counter by the height of one item (the DataGridRow). If CanContentScroll = False, then it can be handled as in the case of the column index loop.

I couldn't find row definitions in the DataGrid for .Net 4.0 in Visual Basic, but the following supporting function helps for obtaining the DataGridRow:

```
Function GetRowByIndex(ByVal p_dataGrid As DataGrid,
                       ByVal p_index As Integer) As DataGridRow
    Dim row As DataGridRow

    row = CType(p_dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(p_index), DataGridRow)
    If IsNothing(row) Then
        'May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.'
        p_dataGrid.UpdateLayout()
        p_dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(p_dataGrid.Items(p_index))
        row = CType(p_dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(p_index), DataGridRow)

    End If
    Return row
End Function
```

And the FindVisualChild function in Visual Basic:

```
Function FindVisualChild(Of childItem As DependencyObject)(ByVal p_obj As DependencyObject) As childItem
    For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(p_obj) - 1
        Dim child As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(p_obj, i)
        If child IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf child Is childItem Then
            Return CType(child, childItem)
        Else
            Dim childOfChild As childItem = FindVisualChild(Of childItem)(child)
            If childOfChild IsNot Nothing Then
                Return childOfChild
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Return Nothing
End Function
```